# Styling a list of numbers on the web

Tags: website-design, css, numbering

I need to display a large list of decimal numbers on the web (~300) all in the range of [-1, 1]. The intent of showing these numbers isn't to display their full precision, but to convey to the user that this is the output from a program. It is a requirement that the actual numbers must be show.

Perhaps not important, but the context of these numbers are coming from a document vector created from a [word embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec).

What I've got so is functional, but ugly. CSS (and design in general) are not skills I have developed, so any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I'd try lining up all the values by placing a space before all non-negative numbers

Comment: It looks like this question isn't a good fit for the site, given the downvote. I'll happily close it and try again elsewhere if this is the case.

Comment: I think the question is kind of related to graphic design since it's about how to make a list of numbers look good. Have you tried what @ZachSaucier suggest? That was my initial thought too.

Comment: I'd use a table. The cells will naturally align the numbers.... and it is tabular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purposes of completeness, I simply arranged the data in a cell as  @Scott suggested in a comment. If a better solution is presented, I'd be happy to select it:

[image]

with the CSS as

```css
.table-row {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-grow: 0;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.text {
    width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: right;
}
```